# Lebesgue Measure, distribution function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let A be a Borel set such that $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$. Prove that for any $0 < \alpha < \mu(A)$ there exists a Borel set $A_{\alpha} \subset A$ such that $\mu(A_\alpha)=\alpha$.
Hint: Consider the sets $B_x = A \cap (-\infty,x]$ and the function $f(x)= \mu(B_x)$.
I follow the hint and set $f(x)= \mu(B_x)$. By the definition, I get $0 \le f(x) \le \mu(A)$. Then, I don't know what I should do for the next step.

Comment: Try showing that $f(x)$ is continuous and using the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up $f$ as in your hint. Fix $x\in\mathbb R$. Then for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $x'\in\mathbb R$ such that $|x'-x|<\varepsilon$. Then 
$$|f(x')-f(x)|=|\mu(B_x)-\mu(B_{x'})|\le|x'-x|<\varepsilon,$$
showing that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ (this is because we have either $B_x\subseteq B_{x'}$ or $B_{x'}\subseteq B_x$. If, without loss of generality, the former holds, then $\mu(B_{x'})=\mu(B_x)+\mu(B_{x'}\backslash B_x)\le \mu(B_x)+|x'-x|$). Then the desired property follows from continuity, as $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(+\infty)=\mu(A)>\alpha$.

Comment: The wording "For each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $x'$ such that $|x'-x|<\varepsilon$ and $|f(x')-f(x)|<\varepsilon$" is not a way to prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$. For, by choosing $x'=x$, those inequalities are always satisfied. What we need to prove is: There exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x')-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x'-x|<\delta$.

Comment: The fact that $f(-\infty) =\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=0$ needs justification (especially in a first course of Real Analysis). For example, if we allow $\mu(A)=\infty$, this is false in general. (For example, if $A=\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x$. Then, of course, the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x])$.
Observe that 
$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{A}(y)\,d\mu(y).
$$
From the general theory of Lebesgue integral, $1_{A}$ is integrable
implies that $f$ is continuous (in fact, absolutely continuous, but
we do not need this fact).

By Monotone Convergence Theorem, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)=\int1_{A}=\mu(A)>\alpha$.
Therefore, there exists $n_{2}$ such that $f(n_{2})>\alpha$. For
each $n$, let $A_{n}=(-\infty,-n]\cap A$. Since $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$,
$\cap_{n}A_{n}=\emptyset$, and $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{n})=\mu(\cap_{n}A_{n})=0<\alpha$.
Choose $n_{1}$ such that $f(-n_{1})=\mu(A_{n_{1}})<\alpha$. By Intermediate
Value Theorem, the results follows.